# mismatched String type in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm currently trying to learn Rust, and when I was trying to follow the official book tutorial I have encountered an error that was not described in the book.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let config = Config::new(&args);
    println!("Searching for {}", config.query);
    println!("In file {}", config.filename);
    println!("{:?}", args);

    let contents = fs::read_to_string(config.filename)
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    println!("With text:\n{}", contents);
}

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}
impl Config {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Config {
        let query = &args[1].clone();
        let filename = &args[2].clone();

        Config { query, filename }
    }
}
```

but I kept getting the following error from the compiler:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:18
   |
25 |         Config { query, filename }
   |                  ^^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&str`
   |                  help: try using a conversion method: `query: query.to_string()`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:25:25
   |
25 |         Config { query, filename }
   |                         ^^^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |                         expected struct `std::string::String`, found `&std::string::String`
   |                         help: try using a conversion method: `filename: filename.to_string()`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I have tried doing something like:

```
        let query = &args[1].clone().to_string();
        let filename = &args[2].clone().to_owned().to_string();
```

but it brought the same error. Finally, I have managed to solve this issue by applying the following changes:

```
struct Config<'a> {
    query: &'a str,
    filename: &'a str,
}
impl Config <'_> {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Config {
        let query = &*args[1];
        let filename = &*args[2];

        Config { query, filename }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that new() could not return a struct of owned strings because values query and filename were assigned referenced values and for some reason, neither of the functions to_string(), to_owned() and clone() were not converting a referenced Sting into an owned one.
Does anyone know why I had to use referenced sices with lifetimes instead of strings?
Also, is there a way to use String type just like in the tutorial(https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the query and file name type is &String, the clone method use &self, You should do like this

```rust
impl Config {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Config {
        let query = args[1].clone();
        let filename = args[2].clone();

        Config { query, filename }
    }
}
```